# Exponent Function in C#

Tags: c#, built-in

i've a string like`1.00E+4`

Is there any built in function to convert this string to `10000`.(Integer convertion [1.00E+4=10000]).?

Now i'm using regular expression for this kind of strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
double.Parse("1.00E+4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Need we specify the `cultureInfo`. ?

Comment: Yes, you should always specify cultureinfo (formatprovider). The result varies depending on the formatprovider you use, so it's generally a good idea to always be specific about this so you don't get unexpected results when running on a machine with a different culture.